# How to animate an Border Background Effect from left to right?

Tags: wpf, xaml

so im quite new to Wpf and was trying to animate something like this particular Animation:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1aSl.gif)

I found something like that to make an Colour Animation:

```
 <EventTrigger 
                        RoutedEvent="TextBox.MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard SlipBehavior="Slip">
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"    
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"   
                                    To="Blue" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger 
                        RoutedEvent="TextBox.MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"    
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"   
                                    To="WhiteSmoke" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
```

Its just change the Color but I want to make it slide from left to right like the example, I know there is Blend to edit those kinda stuff. But I only know how to animate Objects to move but not how to slide the Color From Left to right.

My TextBox style looks like this now, could someone give me a Hint how to manage what I want to get?

```
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
    
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FF7D8683" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="0"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Label Margin="5,0,0,0" x:Name="WaterMarkLabel" Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Gray" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Text" Value=""/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WaterMarkLabel" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DimGray"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <EventTrigger 
                        RoutedEvent="TextBox.MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard SlipBehavior="Slip">
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"    
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"   
                                    To="Blue" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger 
                        RoutedEvent="TextBox.MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border"    
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"   
                                    To="WhiteSmoke" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added MouseEnter and MouseLeave event triggers and used DoubleAnimation to set the width:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <!-- Now we add the MouseEnter event.-->
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">      
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="200" From="20" Duration="0:0:0:0.5" AccelerationRatio="0.5" DecelerationRatio="0.3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <!-- Now we add the MouseLeave event.-->
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="20" Duration="0:0:0:0.5" AccelerationRatio="0.5" DecelerationRatio="0.3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <!-- That's all the codes we add to the default style.-->
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```